# Remove all custom sharepoint 2010 features

Tags: 2010, powershell

I want to remove all custom sharepoint 2010 features from my farm:

The scritp below gets them, but doesn't remove them. How should this be modified to remove them?

```
$url = "Your site URL here"

$site= new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)

$site.WebApplication.Farm.FeatureDefinitions 
| where-object {$_.solutionid -ne '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'} 
| Sort-Object solutionid,displayname 
| ft -property solutionid,displayname,scope -auto > features.txt

$site.Dispose()
```

Adding | $_.Remove() in place of > features.txt causes a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully all your features has been installed through Solution packages to it would be better to retract these and the remove them.

But it may cause a lot of things not to work anymore.